# How can I authorise a client in an OAuth-esque way?

Tags: security, oauth, identification

Let's say I have 2 servers (server and authenticator), and I have a client. My end goal here is to be able to identify the client on server. My solution was to come up with a token/secret system like OAuth: client has a token and secret. It passes it to server. Server passes it to authenticator. If valid, server allows the request.

Obviously, this is nonoptimal just for the number of requests being made. The reason authenticator and server are separated is because this is for a decentralised service-- any number of servers may be used, and it's impractical to ask client libraries to register on each server.

So, the question remains, what's the best/correct way to do this? The goal is to create a system that is decentralised, but can still have clients identify themselves in a relatively secure fashion to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to define my problem a bit better. As I'm only trying to create a way to block applications, I only need to store their name and key when they request the server. Then, as long as they're not blocked and the key matches the one in the datastore, they'll be identified. So I'm not trying to authenticate so much as identify. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not a security expert so I could be off-base here and in actual implementation there seems to be a number of security issues that would need to be ironed out.

In the broadest sense, could you have the client supply credentials to the authenticator and then upon verification the authenticator supplies the client and the server both with matching security tokens and then the client and server can communicate directly?

Just curious about there a reason you don't want to implement OAuth and run your own OAuth server.

Additional reference: http://groups.google.com/group/37signals-api/msg/aeb0c8bf67a224cc